# Laravel SQL groupBy And Sum

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

Here is my tables relation:

```
**reservations** id, date, etc...<br>
**reservation_service_info** service_info_id, reservation_id<br>
**services_info** price etc...
```

I am trying to sum reservation price by day. Here is the code and result:

```
return $query->selectRaw('DATE(start_time) AS date')
        ->selectRaw("(SELECT SUM(price) FROM `services_info` inner join `reservation_service_info` on `services_info`.`id` = `reservation_service_info`.`service_info_id` where `reservation_service_info`.`reservation_id` = reservations.id) as price")
        ->orderBy('date', 'ASC')
        ->get('price', 'date')
```

Result:

```
[
  {
    "date": "2016-06-01",
    "price": "345.00"
  },
  {
    "date": "2016-06-01",
    "price": "90.00"
  },
  {
    "date": "2016-06-01",
    "price": "222.00"
  },
  {
    "date": "2016-06-02",
    "price": "393.00"
  },
  {
    "date": "2016-06-02",
    "price": "142.00"
  }
]
```

When I add `groupBy('date')` in the query it groups it by dosent SUM(price)

```
[
  {
    "date": "2016-06-01",
    "price": "345.00"
  },
  {
    "date": "2016-06-02",
    "price": "393.00"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This :

```
                 $users=   DB::table('reservation_service_info')
                     ->join('services_info', 'reservation_service_info.service_info_id', '=', 'services_info.id')
                     ->join('reservations', 'reservation_service_info.reservation_id', '=', 'reservations.id')
                     ->select('DATE(reservations.start_time) AS date','SUM(services_info.price) AS price')
                     ->orderBy('reservations.start_time', 'ASC')
                     ->groupBy('reservations.start_time')
                     ->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that your query is been built in a bit wrong way. I would suggest this way of thinking:

```
return $query->select(\DB::raw('DATE(start_time) AS date'), \DB::raw('SUM(price) as price'))
        ->join('reservation_service_info', 'reservations.id', '=', 'reservation_service_info.reservation_id')
        ->join('services_info', 'services_info.id', '=', 'reservation_service_info.services_info_id')
        ->orderBy('date', 'ASC')
        ->groupBy('date')
        ->get();
```

This should work if the `$query` table is `reservations`.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `sum(price)` to get sum:

```
return $query->selectRaw('DATE(start_time) AS date')
        ->selectRaw("(SELECT SUM(price) FROM `services_info` inner join `reservation_service_info` on `services_info`.`id` = `reservation_service_info`.`service_info_id` where `reservation_service_info`.`reservation_id` = reservations.id) as price")
        ->orderBy('date', 'ASC')
        ->groupBy('date')
        ->get();
```

Comment: Yeah I tried that but I get same effect because this select query is just selecting one row...

Comment: @user3806764 Could you edit your question and show desired result then?